# Создание анимированных персонажей

Tags: java, unity3d, разработка-игр, canvas, webgl

Хочу спросить. Какие технологии используются для создания анимированных персонажей на платформа Android и/или iOS.

Я хочу создать персонажей, похожих на кота их игры "Говорящий Том". В моем случае, они также будет иметь набор стандартной анимации, но качество должно быть хорошим. Кроме стандартных анимаций, существуют предметы, которые могут использовать разные персонажи.

Накидал изображения для придачи ясности. Спасибо.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения] [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Spine посмотрите

Answer (score 0):

Ну, смотря по игре. Если игра 3D то можно использовать Cinema4D для анимации. Если игра векторная, то можно покадрово отрисовывать анимацию персонажа.